# Codewars - Balance the Parentheses - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Trying to solve [this codewars challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/balance-the-parentheses/train/javascript):

> Your job is to fix the parentheses so that all opening and closing parentheses (brackets) have matching counterparts. You will do this by appending parenthesis to the beginning or end of the string. The result should be of minimum length. Don't add unnecessary parenthesis.
>
> The input will be a string of varying length, only containing '(' and/or ')'.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> Input: ")("
> Output: "()()"
>
> Input: "))))(()("
> Output: "(((())))(()())"
> ```

My idea is to create a 'stack', and then push that stack onto a final array when we encounter an 'opposite' parentheses.

```js
const fixParentheses = (str) => {
  let array = Array.from(str);
  let final = [];
  let stack = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    if (array[j] === ')' && array[j + 1] === ')'){
      stack.push(')');
    }
    if (array[j] === ')' && array[j + 1] === '(') {
      stack.push(')');
      stack.unshift('('.repeat(stack.length));
      stack = stack.join();
      stack = stack.replace(/[,]/gi, '');
      final.push(stack);
      stack = [];
    }
    if (array[j] === '(' && array[j + 1] === '(') {
      stack.push('(');
    }
    if (array[j] === '(' && array[j + 1] === ')') {
      stack.push('(');
      stack.push(')'.repeat(stack.length));
      stack = stack.join();
      stack = stack.replace(/[,]/gi, '');
      final.push(stack);
      stack = [];
    }
  }
return final.join('');
}
console.log(fixParentheses('))))(()('));
```

Desired output: `'(((())))(()())'`

The problem is that this is balancing, but not in the correct order.

I don't know how to account for situations where we see `(()(`, without the function becoming too complex (which it already is).

Also, can you please explain to me why I'm currently having to separate my array methods on separate lines? I.e. why does

```
stack.push('(');
stack.push(')').repeat(stack.length));
stack = stack.join();
stack = stack.replace(/[,]/gi, '');
```

not produce an error, but `stack.push('(').push(')'.repeat(stack.length)).join().replace(/[,]/gi, '');` does? I'd like to optimize.

Comment: Your last portion throws an error because you can't chain array methods to `push()`; [it returns a number.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Return_value)

Comment: Okay so you can always chain as long as the return value is something that you can continue to add another method to i.e. `myString.concat('world').split('');` works because `.concat` returns a string and `.split()` is a string method.

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more concise alternative:

1. Remove all parentheses with an adjacent match, i.e. `"()"`.
2. Repeat this until there are no more. This leaves you with only the unmatched parentheses.
3. Count how many `)` you have in the string. This is how many `(` you will need to add to the beginning.
4. Count how many `(` you have in the string. This is how many `)` you will need to add to the end.

```js
const fixParentheses = (str) => {
  let orig = str;

  //Repeatedly remove all instances of "()" until there are none left
  while (str.includes("()"))
    str = str.replace(/\(\)/g, '');
    
  //Count the number of ")" and "(" left in the string
  let amtOpeningParensNeeded = (str.match(/\)/g) || []).length;
  let amtClosingParensNeeded = (str.match(/\(/g) || []).length;
  
  //Add that many "(" and ")" to the string, respectively
  return "(".repeat(amtOpeningParensNeeded) + orig + ")".repeat(amtClosingParensNeeded);
};

//You can ignore this, it's just a wrapper for demo/logging purposes
const test = input => { console.log(`Input: ${input}`); console.log(`Output: ${fixParentheses(input)}`)};

test(")(");
test("))))(()(");
```

---

> Why do I have to separate my array methods into new lines? Why does `stack.push('(').push(')'.repeat(stack.length)).join().replace(/[,]/gi, '');` throw an error?

You cannot chain additional Array methods to [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) because it does not return an Array; it returns an [*integer* representing the new `length` of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Return_value).

For all intents and purposes, `["apples","oranges"].push("banana").join()` is the same as doing `3.join()`.